# How can I model regularity?

Tags: regularization

I have data that are a result of **rules** that are **exceptionless**. I want to my program to *'look'* at my data and figure out those rules. However, the data might contain what might look like an exception (rule within a rule) but that is too, true for all occasions e.g.

All men of the dataset with x common characteristics go out for a beer on Thursday after work. That is true for all men with those characteristics. However, they will cancel their plans if their wife is sick. That last condition might initially look as an exception to the rule (go out for beer on Thursdays), but it is not as long as it is true for all men with those x characteristics.

**So the question is**: *Which approach/method would be suitable for this?*